# How to insert multiple JavaScript variables to collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that requires fields that are from calculations. I completed the calculations and stored the results in variables. However, I can not insert all the variables into the collection, it only adds the first variable.

For example: 
db.foo.insert(a,b,c);

a, b, c being javascript variables.

How would I fix this to print all variables in mongoDB format?
The variables look like:
var a = {"sum": 14}

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for `insertMany()` function.

In your case that would look something like this:

`db.foo.insertMany([a, b, c])`

Here is [the link to the official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/).

Comment: If I could see a larger piece of code, I could be of better help :)
`insertMany()` accepts an array of JavaScript objects by definition.